# Is there a way to filter multiple class objects in views.py and connect to each other?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a Django project where I want to make 3 menus that can be accessed by clicking the select button in each

main_menu(like mainfood) >> menu(pastas) >> items of pastas(bluh bluh)

*main_menu is accessed from the homepage*

I have created 3 classes in `models.py` called `MainMenu`,  `Menu`, `Item`

```
class MainMenu(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    main_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Date created", default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    

class Menu(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Date created", default=timezone.now)
    main_menus = models.ForeignKey(MainMenu,default="",verbose_name="Menus",on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}||{self.main_menus}"    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']


class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Date created", default=timezone.now)
    menus = models.ForeignKey(Menu,default="",verbose_name="Menus",on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}||{self.menus}"
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
```

and I have filtered objects in `views.py`

```
def menus(request,main_slug):
    matching_menus = Menu.objects.filter(main_menus__main_slug=main_slug).all()
    return render(
        request=request,
        template_name='Menu.html',
        context={"objects": matching_menus}
        )

def items(request,slug):
    matching_items = Item.objects.filter(menus__slug=slug).all()
    return render(
        request=request,
        template_name='Item.html',
        context={"objects": matching_items}
        )
```

and the `urls.py` :

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path('<slug:main_slug>', views.menus),
    path('<str:slug>', views.items),
]
```

it kinda WORKS but only menu is filtered correctly.

I can go from MainMenu to Menu and the Menus are filtered correctly,

but I CANNOT access the items in the Menus. when I click a menu like "pastas" it loads up a blank menu html and doesn't give any errors.

tried to connect three menus but ended up connecting only two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it's always matching the url for the menus. In your example, the string "pastas" can be matched both as a slug and as a string. Since the url for the menus is listed first, that is the one that is selected by Django.

To fix it, use different urls for the different pages, for example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('main_menu/<slug:main_slug>', views.menus),
    path('menu/<str:slug>', views.items),
]
```